# Can we generate yahoo API key with domain name that contains digit?

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I have problem to generate yahoo api key.

Can we generate yahoo API key with domain name that contains digit. ie. Test123.com?

Comment: Please remember that we cannot read your mind. What exact event led you to think that the mechanism to generate API keys differs for alphanumeric domain names? It's a shocking idea because domain names are, well, just *names*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate yahoo API key and how to use it in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990893/how-to-generate-yahoo-api-key-and-how-to-use-it-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! You can create an app key here: http://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html